# "Enter" doesn't work in VS Code for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I installed Anaconda. Somehow, afterwards, when I press Enter in Python files, it no longer works. This error shows up:

> command 'pythonIndent.newlineAndIndent' not found

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking your keybindings.json file, also disable all VS Code extensions and install them one by one. Maybe it's caused by some buggy extension.

Comment: I uninstalled an extension called Python Indent and resolved the problem. No idea why it was installed in the first place.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. I solved the problem by uninstalling an extension called "Python Indent"

Answer (score 3):

uninstall python indent from vs code then again  download the same extension.Hopefully now it works properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Search `Enter` in Keyboard Shortcuts and see if your wanted one is list there:

[image]

If not, search with your wanted effect that `enter` brings and see if you changed the keybindings, which you can see your customization in `keybindings.json`.

Or disable the third-party extension but only keep **Python**.

If the above don't work, you may [reset VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code).

Answer (score 0):

One work around is "ctrl + Enter" instead of only pressing "Enter".